# ¿Cómo quitar WP de mi URL web? - Wordpress Elementor

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirección, elementor

Hace poco levanté un sitio web Wordpress Elementor, e instalé wordpress en un subdirectorio de nombre WP.
Ahora al entrar al sitio, este redirigue a la URL - ejemplo.cl/wp/.

Quisiera que el /wp/ no apareciera en el sitio, solo de modo visual.
Hasta ahora eh tocado el .htaccess varias veces sin lograr cambiar nada.

Me olvidaba agregar que si cambio la configuración de Wordpress, Elementor no funciona. Por eso no lo puedo hacer desde ahi.

Este es el archivo, sustituí mi sitio por ejemplo.cl:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?ejemplo.cl$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?ejemplo.cl$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Si además alguien me puede explicar como funcionan las reglas de esto, le agradecería mucho.

Comment: ¿Tu Wordpress está instalado en la carpeta `wp`?

Comment: Si, por ahi leí que una opción es moverlo a la carpeta raíz.

Comment: Eso sería lo más normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacer esto, aunque puedes moverlo a la raíz, esto no modificara la url de la base de datos, por lo que aun debes modificar la url, aqui te dejo algunas formas.

1. Una forma fácil es agregar al wp-config.php lo siguiente:

   define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );

   define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );

Esto obligará a wordpress a cargar en una dirección diferente, mientras tu htaccess aún apunte a la carpeta la redirección debería funcionar perfectamente.

2. Desde la base de datos, busca la tabla wp-options y cambia el siteurl y home, agregando la url por la cual quieres reemplazarlo, el prefijo {wp} puede variar según lo hayas configurado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y por último, la más fácil, es modificarlo directamente desde los ajustes de wordpress.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como nota importante, en caso de mover el sitio a la raíz, aun debes de actualizar el .htaccess, para eso puedes simplemente volverlo a su estado por defecto, tampoco olvides que la url no puede terminar en "/".

Aquí el htaccess por defecto de un wordpress normal.

## BEGIN WordPress

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

Y si es multisite dependera del modo que hayas escogido, puedes leer más aqui https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/htaccess/

Comment: La opción directa de Wordpress la intenté pero seguro puse mal la URL por que se caía el sitio. Gracias por la confirmación.

Comment: Jeff, por alguna razón el login de wordpress dejó de funcionar, tuve que revertir el cambio.

Comment: Si haces el cambio y reseteas el htaccess puede que aun necesites remover la  cache o probar en incognito, también puede que necesites poner en tu header la función flush_rewrite_rules(); para que los enlaces permanentes vuelvan a crearse.

Comment: Como reseteo el htaccess para que eso ocurra y donde va esa función ? asi probar

Comment: La funcion la podes poner en el header.php de tu tema y el htaccess, puedes borrarlo o solo reemplazar el contenido por el htaccess default que deje en la respuesta o copiarla de la url

Comment: Intenté todo eso, pero siempre se rompió el sitio :/